# PyCharm и разница между средами использования

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, pipenv, poetry

Я изучаю IDE под названием "PyCharm", да и python в целом. Заметил, что там можно выбрать "среду использования". Я не понимаю между ними разницу, в инете нет нормальной информации, на этом сайте что-то было, но в итоге оказалось, что это про разницу между "Env" и "Virtualenv". И вот в чем впорос: Какая разница между "Virtualenv", "Pipenv", "Poetry" и "Conda"?